# How to implement predefined attribute filters in an Openlayers web map?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, select-by-attribute

I imagine this situation: I've got relatively big point layer and I want to split(filter) the points to predefined selections.
Predefined selection would be based on the attribute(for example Name:John, Type:Highway etc.)
**Users must be abble to turn the selections on/off **

Think that something like wfs filter should be usefull

Better said wfs filter is great and I only want to put its functionality to a checkbox, button, form or whatever what user will be able to set up(his own way)

```
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "TYPE",
                        value: "highway"}),
```

Where can I find something about this theme? Or how to solve it?

Thanks for all the advices.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where you are stuck. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can use a **[CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/)** layer in GeoJSON format. This [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cartodb-geojson.html) shows how to load a CartoDB vector layer and perform a PostGIS query on it, so it could be a good starting point.

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors", {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
        url: "http://examples.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql",
        params: {
            q: "select * from costa_rica_pa LIMIT 50",
            format: "geojson"
        },
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
            ignoreExtraDims: true
        }),
        callbackKey: "callback"
    }),
    eventListeners: {
        "featuresadded": function() {
            this.map.zoomToExtent(this.getDataExtent());
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks man but I need to build my own app

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

> http://demo.mapfish.org/mapfishsample/2.2/

When you try, for instance, the "search" option and then "type", you can choose one option (eg. fastfood), and all those points are selected. It uses WMS btw, which in this sense is usually faster than WFS for big data sets (<1k features).

Hope this helps you,

Comment: It looks good. I want something like the search button. But from this site It is not clear enough(for me) how to do that. Anyway thank you